# Fullcalendar 4 alpha problem with jalali (Persian) calendar view

Tags: fullcalendar, alpha, jalali-calendar

I want to use fullcalendar 4 alpha, because of it's better support for "fa Locale".
it use jalali calendar but It have one issue that [I wrote in one issue](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4397).

It convert Gregorian days and month names to jalali but it's view has problem.
It's month doesn't start correctly and in jalali month view .

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Not yet. You can post issue in fullcalendar github page.